# laravel : call method from same class in model

Tags: laravel

in the model i have function serverApi, in the same model i want to call those function, but command error undefined function
there is error when i call function getProvince() there is serverApi function inside

i use $this this::, change public function serverApi become private but still same issue

```php
class Tracking extends Model
{   
    private function serverApi($url){
        $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "key: 1a8aef03546713fdc55870b8b640a2c6"
            ),
            ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {return $err;} else { return $response;}
    }
    public function getProvince(){
        $url = "https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province";
        serverApi($url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` should to the trick:

```
public function getProvince(){
    $url = "https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province";
    return $this->serverApi($url);
}
```

Comment: oh that working, but why the return is null, when i var_dump($return) is null

Comment: You should `return` the result. I updated my answer.